# How to prove P(Y | X, Z) = P(Y | Z)

Tags: probability

I want to prove $P(Y \mid X, Z) =  P(Y \mid Z)$ given that we know $P(X, Y\mid Z) = P(X \mid Z)P(Y \mid Z)$.

How do I do that?

This is how far I have gotten but I am stuck:
\begin{align}
P(X, Y \mid Z) & = \frac{P(X, Y, Z)}{P(Z)} \\
           & = \frac{P(X, Z)}{P(Z)} \times \frac{P(X, Y, Z)}{P(X, Z)} \\
           & =P(Y \mid X, Z) ~P(X \mid Z)\\
           & = \frac{P(X, Y \mid Z)}{P(X \mid Z)}
\end{align}

Thanks

Comment: What does $P(X,Y|Z)$ here mean? Are $X,Y$ random variables or sets? You seem to use $P$ to denote the cdf but you use $p$ to denote the pdf. But traditionally $P$ is just used to denote the probability and not cdf --- where the traditional notation is $F$.

Answer (score 6):

We assume that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are events (i.e., sets). Then,
\begin{align*}
P(Y\mid XZ) &=\frac{P(XYZ)}{P(XZ)}\\
&=\frac{P(XY\mid Z)P(Z)}{P(X\mid Z) P(Z)}\\
&=\frac{P(X\mid Z)P(Y\mid Z)P(Z)}{P(X\mid Z) P(Z)}\\
&=P(Y\mid Z).
\end{align*}